# Getting XML in JAX-RS service

Tags: java, xml, url, service, jax-rs

How can I get XML and/or URL (String) in JAX-RS service?

For example in GET method URL

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml; charset=UTF-8")
public JaxrsPriceWrapper getPrice(@QueryParam("firstId"), @QueryParam("materialId"),...) {
    //here I would like to get whole URL
}
```

and in POST method XML

```
@POST
public JaxrsOrderWrapper insertOrder(OrderJaxrsVO jaxrsVO) {
    //here the XML
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me using Jersey. Add a variable;

`@Context private UriInfo uriInfo;`

.. to your resource class. This will be made available to the resource methods. You can then call

`uriInfo.getRequestURI()`.

Example;

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("/jerseytest")
public class Server
{
    @Context private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String get()
    {
        System.out.println("jerseytest called: URI = " + uriInfo.getRequestUri());

        return "<response>hello world</response>";
    }
}
```

Edit:
You probably need to annotate your POST method with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` to get the data posted.